# Как объединить 2 таблицы определённым образом

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `groups`
```

И есть запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) donor_posts_count FROM `donor_posts` WHERE `group_id` = '{$group_id}' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) < time
```

Как мне объединить их таким образом что бы результат выдавал список имеющихся групп а также добавлялся столбец где была бы информация о количестве записей за сегодняшний день у определённой группы.

Структура `groups`:

```
`id`, `group_id`
```

Структура `donor_posts`:

```
`id`, group_id, `post_id`, `time`
```

Отдельно результаты работают, но это получается 2 запроса за одно выполнение скрипта, я хочу сократить до 1 запроса. Но не могу сообразить как, пробовал пример разные, ничего не получается. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил того что хочу добиться. Спасибо за внимание.

Хочу что бы получилось вот так:

```
group_id | donor_posts_count
62728829 | 24
12312444 | 77
12312312 | 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1(предпочтительней):

```
SELECT 
  g.`group_id`,
  COUNT(p.`group_id`) donor_posts_count 
FROM 
  `groups` g
  LEFT JOIN `donor_posts` p on p.`group_id`= g.`group_id`
GROUP BY g.`group_id`
```

Вариант 2(эксперементов ради, может тормозить):

```
SELECT 
  g.`group_id`,
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM 
      `donor_posts` p
    WHERE 
      g.`group_id` = p.`group_id`
  ) donor_posts_count 
FROM 
  `groups` g
```

Спасибо @Mike за дополнение =)

PS. В связи с выясненым в комментариях:

```
SELECT 
  g.`group_id`,
  COUNT(p.`group_id`) donor_posts_count 
FROM 
  `groups` g
  LEFT JOIN `posts` p 
    on p.`group_id`= g.`group_id` 
    and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) < p.time
GROUP BY g.`group_id`
ORDER BY g.`group_id`
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87406/discussion-on-answer-by-----2---).