# Посчитать количество комментариев для каждой записи

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы:

```
pages с полями id и url
comments с полями page_id
```

В таблице pages на каждую страницу приходится свой уникальный id и url.
В таблице comments в поле page_id содержится id страницы, на которые оставлены комментарии. В этом поле могут быть одинаковые page_id, так как комментариев может быть оставлено несколько на одну страницу.

Нужно посчитать количество комментариев к каждой выводимой записи. Я так понимаю нужно делать LEFT JOIN?

ДОБАВЛЕНО, так как по приведенной ссылке не совсем то, что нужно. Выполнил задачу следующим кодом, но мне кажется это будет работать медленнее, чем выполнить LEFT JOIN. Подскажите пожалуйста что лучше тут сделать?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE url = 'https://site.ru/news/55/'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$pageid = $r['id'];

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE page_id = $pageid";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $r[0];
}}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как объединить 2 таблицы определённым образом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924167/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Поправил вопрос, посмотрите

Comment: `select p.id, count(c.page_id) cnt from pages p left join comments c on c.page_id = p.id` читаете из него как обычно и `$r['cnt']` будет содержать количество записей.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pages.id as id, count(*) as count from pages left join comments on pages.id = comments.pag_id group by pages.id
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста.