# Определить у кого больше записей php

Tags: php, mysql

Господа и дамы! Как вывести пользователя у кого больше выполненных заданий. 
Таблица users и таблица quests_active (сюда записываются id заданий и id пользователей) необходимо пользователя, у кого больше заданий.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924171/194569 отсортировать по количеству и взять первую запись (`order by cnt desc limit 1`)

Answer (score 0):

Делаем join двух таблиц, группируем по user.id, сортируем в обратном порядке по количеству сообщений и берем первое значение.

```
select *
from users u
left join quests_active qa on (u.id = qa.user_id)
group by u.id
order by count(*) desc 
limit 1;
```