# Подсчет кол-ва и суммы столбца в сложном запросе JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Не могу разобраться с обьединениями.

Имеется 2 таблицы A (id, name) и B(id, A_id, number).

Необходимо вывести все элементы A, с подсчетом суммы Number и кол-ва строк по условию ON `A`.`id`=`B`.`A_id`.

Пример:

A:

```
id, name 
 1  Ваня
 2  Игорь
 3  Женя
 4  Коля
```

B:

```
id, A_id  number 
 1   1      10
 2   1      20
 3   3      5
 4   4      1
```

Нужно получить:

```
id, name,  number, Count()
 1  Ваня    30      2
 2  Игорь    0      0
 3  Женя     5      1 
 4  Коля     1      1
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924171/194569

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH exmpleCTE AS (
    SELECT
        B.A_id as aID,
        SUM(B.number) as s,
        COUNT(B.A_id) as c
    FROM B
    GROUP BY B.A_id
)
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.name,
    e.s,
    e.c
FROM A
LEFT JOIN exampleCTE e ON A.id = e.aID
ORDER BY A.id
```

Так как подсчет по `id = 2` вернет `NULL` по поля `s` и `c`, то при выводе надо еще использовать конструкцию `IF`:

```
IF(e.s IS NULL, '0', e.s)
```

Comment: А ничего, что: 1. в вопросе метка MySQL, а ходовые его версии не умеют WITH. 2. `IF(e.s = NULL ...` не может работать потому что оператор = не сравнивает с null и тогда уж надо использовать IS NULL. функции IF нет в большинстве СУБД, поддерживающих with. А вообще есть SQL 92 совместимая функция coalesce(), дающая аналогичный результат

Comment: @Mike Так `CTE` же добавили вроде начиная с `8.0`, нет? По поводу `if` согласен, ошибся немного.

Comment: Да, добавили, только 8 пока слишком мало распространена. Да и громозко это, проще подзапрос во from. Ну и есть ли от него толк отдельный вопрос, в большинстве случаев оптимизаторы отлично справляются и с прямым join двух таблиц до group by. Хотя тут не угадаешь, может так и лучше по скорости будет. И все таки `coalesce(s.e, 0)` покороче.

Comment: @Mike к сожалению о распространении `mysql` не осведомлен. Сам в основном `mssql` использую

Comment: А чего сложно-то так? Нафига тут вообще CTE - и так сошло бы... а заодно не пришлось бы спорить про 8-ю версию.