# Mysql Join с лимитом

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос
Допустим есть таблица с полями:

`store_id
title
desc`

И есть таблица с фото:

`photo_id
url
store_id`

Как составить запрос,чтобы я получал массив всех объектов из таблицы 1 с одним фото из таблицы 2 у соответствующих store_id,надеюсь понятно объяснил)
Работает так:
Я вывожу объекты списком и мне нужно чтобы у каждого объекта было 1(в базе их может быть больше) фото рядом с карточкой этого объекта.

Comment: уточните версию СУБД

Comment: Какие нибудь предпочтения по тому, какую фотку брать есть ? Если нет и от картинки нужен только url, то делаете join двух таблиц, добавляете group by по всем выбираемым полям первой таблицы и в фразе select берете например min(url)

Comment: Фотка нужна любая,какую вытащит,использую Mysql+php. Не могу понять как составить запрос сам...

Comment: Например как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924167/194569 только вместо количества (count) берете минимальный url `min(url)`

Comment: @Mike Лучше [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) - зачем нужна лишняя сортировка?

Comment: @Akina Да, определенно лучше, не знал что в mysql такая есть

Comment: @Mike , посмотрел что вы скинули,честно не очень понял как в моем случае это реализовать) с mysql туго у меня..Но спасибо,попробую

Comment: `$statement = $this->conn->prepare( "SELECT tbl_storefinder_stores.store_id,SUBSTRING(`store_desc`, 1, 125),store_name,category_id, lat, lon, telephone, keywords, tbl_storefinder_photos.photo_url FROM `tbl_storefinder_stores` JOIN `tbl_storefinder_photos` ON (`tbl_storefinder_stores`.`store_id` = `tbl_storefinder_photos`.`store_id` )");` вот при таком запросе,у меня запись дублирует столько раз,сколько есть фото. Если я делаю `min` то выводится одна первая запись.